# Can javascript acess data from a csv file in the same directory and turn it into a javascript object which it can work with?

Tags: javascript

I have a html, javascript and csv file in the same directory. I would like javascript to take the data from the csv file and show it as a tabel in html. Is this possible to do? how can you use javascript to store data from a csv file into a javascript object.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but not from a browser.

Comment: wonderful! could you elaborate more, or maybe link to a resource where i could learn about it. Would be much appreciated!

Comment: use something like https://www.papaparse.com/

Comment: @NilsLorentzon Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/1293147/9253414